# how to efficiently check if the Levenshtein edit distance between two string is 1

Tags: string, algorithm, edit-distance

please note that it doesn't require to really calculate Levenshtein edit distance. just check it's 1 or not.

The signature of the method may look like this:

```
bool Is1EditDistance(string s1, string s2).
```

for example:
1. "abc" and "ab" return true
2. "abc" and "aebc" return true
3. "abc" and "a" return false.

I've tried recursive approve, but it it not efficient.

---

update: got answer from a friend:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length && i < s2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s1[i] != s2[i])
            {
                return s1.Substring(i + 1) == s2.Substring(i + 1)   //case of change
                    || s1.Substring(i + 1) == s2.Substring(i)       //case of s1 has extra
                    || s1.Substring(i) == s2.Substring(i + 1);      //case of s2 has extra
            }
        }
        return Math.Abs(s1.Length - s2.Length) == 1;
```

Comment: Which edit distance? Levenshtein? Hamming?

Comment: Could you flesh out this question a bit more? Perhaps tell us what you have tried?

Comment: there are multiple types of distances defined b/w strings..Jaro–Winkler distance , Hamming , Levenshtein...which one ?

Comment: Uses dynamic programming algo , I know only the recursive version...http://www.lemoda.net/c/levenshtein/index.html

Answer (score 7):

If you only care if the distance is exactly 1 or not, you can do something like this:

- If the difference of the strings' lengths is not 0 or 1, return false.
- If both strings have length `n`, loop `i = 0..n` checking `s1[i] == s2[i]` for all `i` except one.
- If the strings have length `n` and `n+1`, let `i` be the smallest index where `s1[i] != s2[i]`, then loop `j=i..n` checking `s1[j] == s2[j+1]` for all `j`.

Comment: This is the most efficient solution. This is far superior to running a variant of the levenshtein algorithm where a max distance is specified and you give up once it becomes apparent that the max distance has been exceeded.